# uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::RAILS_ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added this to my application.html.erb file:

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/ga' if RAILS_ENV == 'production' %>
```

And I get the error `uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::RAILS_ENV` on this exact line.

When I take the `if RAILS_ENV == 'production'` off, the error goes away but isn't this suppose to work fine? What does the error tries to tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RAILS_ENV` should be a key in environment variable array `ENV`.  Try:

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/ga' if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == 'production' %>
```

or,

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/ga' if Rails.env.production? %>
```